# 403 when opening "/mw-config/index.php" for configuring MediaWiki on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, mediawiki

I'm following [this guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Windows#Installing_MediaWiki)

When I try to open `http://domain/directory/mw-config/index.php` with `domain=localhost` and `directory=C:/wamp/www/wiki` I get:

```
Forbidden  

You don't have permission to access /C:/wamp/www/wiki/mw-config/index.php on this server.   
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) PHP/5.6.19 Server at localhost Port 80
```

How to solve this?

The URL I am using is

```
localhost/C:/wamp/www/wiki/mw-config/index.php
```

Comment: Show us exactly what you are entering into the browser address bar, please dont make us guess

Comment: http://localhost/C:/wamp/www/wiki/mw-config/index.php

WAMP is located on C:/wamp
Mediawiki on C:/wamp/www/wiki/
I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a correct url.

There should be no reference to anything like `C:/wamp`

A correct url would be `localhost/wiki/mw-config/index.php`

You have a web server now so urls should look pretty much like they do on a real site i.e. `example.com/folder/file.php` except you use `localhost` instead of `example.com`